# MySQL: How to find similar characters in a string

Tags: mysql, sql

New to SQL, and having problems coming up with Query that will show an acceptable result.

Say I have a table that has 3 strings:

- 11111A111B1
- 22222A222B2
- 33333A333B3

All strings have the same number of characters.

I want a result that shows which characters are the same and at what position. So using the example above, the result should show something like the 6th character A and 10th character B are the same in the table.

Comment: are you looking for characters that are the same in all strings or between each couple?

Comment: This doesn't seem like something that's easy in SQL. What do you want the result to look like?

Comment: SQL has functions to test if two strings are the same or look for patterns in the string. But there's nothing that will return a list of differences, you'd have to write a stored function that loops over the characters.

Comment: This code is going to be painfully verbose in pure SQL

Comment: Looking for characters that are the same in all strings and same location. So the Query should tell me which character and which location is the same in the whole table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said your string lengths are all the same. And you also don't need to return the actual string, but rather, which character is found in the same position of more than one string. You could UNION a bunch of queries and then select from it.

```
create table my_data (
  id integer, 
  string_column varchar(20)
  );
  
insert into my_data values 
(1, '11111A111B1'), 
(2, '22222A222B2'), 
(3, '33333A333B3');
```

---

```
select position, string_char, t_count
from (
  select 'pos1' as position, substring(string_column, 1, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos2' as position, substring(string_column, 2, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos3' as position, substring(string_column, 3, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos4' as position, substring(string_column, 4, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos5' as position, substring(string_column, 5, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos6' as position, substring(string_column, 6, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos7' as position, substring(string_column, 7, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos8' as position, substring(string_column, 8, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos9' as position, substring(string_column, 9, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos10' as position, substring(string_column, 10, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  union
  select 'pos11' as position, substring(string_column, 11, 1) as string_char, count(id) as t_count
  from my_data
  group by 1,2
  )z
where t_count > 1;
```

| position | string_char | t_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pos6 | A | 3 |
| pos10 | B | 3 |

---

**UPDATE**

And if you want to require that character and position to be the same for ALL rows, then change `>1` to `=nbr of rows you have`.

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t2jyCvLuFtWrCykWgjLpCr/1)